# Changing tabbing space and hotkeys in Emacs for C++

Tags: c++, emacs

I'm completely new to linux/emacs (Using GNU Emacs 24.4.1 on debian) and I'm finding it incredibly frustrating to use. I'm trying to program in C++, however I'm finding the tab spacing is very small, it's not even a tab it's literally just a single space how do I fix this? I've tried adding this to my .emacs file in home but it didn't fix anything:

```
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)
(setq-default tab-width 4)
(setq indent-line-function 'insert-tab)
```

Is it also possible to change copy/cut/paste/undo to the original

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can skip the config file for now and just use the GUI:

> - Options   -> Customize Emacs  -> Top-level Customization Group  -> Editing  -> Indent

You might also consider checking out "smart-tabs" if you want tab to insert spaces instead of tab characters: Smart Tabs (tabs for indentation, spaces for alignment) http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SmartTabs

As for changing the cut/copy/paste commands, try CuaMode (should be installed by default on Emacs 22.1.1 and later):

> M-x cua-mode

That will change many of your editing hotkeys around to the more "standard" versions.  See more info here: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CuaMode

(I would, however, recommend *against* that, as it will delay the Emacs learning process.  The standard commands become second-nature in a short while, and learning them will guarantee that you aren't stuck using nano or gedit if you have to shell into someplace with an older version of Emacs).

Answer (score 0):

To change the indentation of c-like modes (c, c++, java, etc.) use

```
(setq c-basic-offset 4)
```